# BeautifulSoup does not find any XML tags

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract words with specific properties from an XML dictionary. For instance, all the verbs, indicated by *Type* under *Lemma* . Then I will subdivide those entries based on definition or *Inflection* . But for now, I just need to explore the Beautifulsoup object.
I am quite new to XML. Here is the first entry in the dictionary. I closed it to make it valid XML (I hope).
I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_python_beautifulsoup/)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Dictionary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="lexinAA.xsd">
  <Article ArticleID="1000002" Sortkey="a">
    <Lemma ID="1000002" LemmaID="1" Rank="350" Type="subst." Value="a" Variant="" VariantID="3, 4">
      <Phonetic File="v2/100021_1.mp3">a:</Phonetic>
      <Inflection Form="best.f.sing.">a:et</Inflection>
      <Inflection Form="obest.f.pl.">a:n</Inflection>
      <Inflection Form="best.f.pl.">a:na</Inflection>
      <Index Value="a" />
      <Index Value="a:et" />
      <Index Value="a:n" />
      <Index Value="a:na" />
      <Index Value="as" />
      <Index Value="a:ets" />
      <Index Value="a:ns" />
      <Index Value="a:nas" />
      <Lexeme ID="1" LexemeID="1000006" Lexemeno="1" VariantID="3">
        <Definition ID="9011000">första bokstaven i alfabetet</Definition>
        <Idiom DoubleID="2060026" ID="1000008" OldID="2">a och o
          <Definition DoubleID="2030380" ID="1000009">det viktigaste</Definition>
        </Idiom>
        <Idiom DoubleID="2060590" ID="1000010" OldID="1">har man sagt a får man också säga b
          <Definition DoubleID="2030824" ID="1000011">har man börjat får man fortsätta</Definition>
        </Idiom>
      </Lexeme>
      <Lexeme ID="2" LexemeID="1000013" Lexemeno="2" VariantID="4">
        <Definition ID="9011001">sjätte tonen i C-durskalan</Definition>
        <Compound ID="2000667" OldID="">a-moll</Compound>
        <Compound ID="2000668" OldID="">A-dur</Compound>
        <Index Value="a-moll" />
        <Index Value="a-molls" />
        <Index Value="a moll" />
        <Index Value="a molls" />
        <Index Value="A-dur" />
        <Index Value="A-durs" />
        <Index Value="A dur" />
        <Index Value="A durs" />
      </Lexeme>
    </Lemma>
  </Article>
</Dictionary>
```

Here is my Beautifulsoup code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


content = []
with open('swe_swe.xml', 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, 'lxml')

result = bs_content.find('Article')
print(result)
print(bs_content.find('Inflection Form="best.f.sing.">a:et'))
```

The result of both prints is *None* .

What I'm expecting from the 'Article' tag is either the entire first entry for the first word 'a', or just the line:

```
ArticleID="1000002" Sortkey="a">
```

The tags in the dictionary look completely different to what is in the tutorial, so I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact output you expect from the two `print()` statements in your code (or any other expected output)? Also, since you are importing lxml, can you use that instead of BS?

Comment: @JackFleeting I made the changes, but since BS imports lxml anyway, I just removed lxml. I still want to use BeautifulSoup, since I found lxml to be tricky in a previous attempt.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler if you use css selectors, in this case. Note that element names are in lower case. For example, to get the text of `<Article>`:

```
for s in soup.select_one('article').stripped_strings:
          print(s)
```

Another example:

```
print(soup.select_one('inflection[form="best.f.sing."]'))
```

outputs

```
<inflection form="best.f.sing.">a:et</inflection>
```

Finally, to get the attribute value of `LexemeID` in `Lexeme` elements:

```
for lex in soup.select('lexeme'):
    print(lex.attrs['lexemeid'])
```

Outputs:

```
1000006
1000013
```

etc.

Comment: @Glubbdrubb Indeed! As an aside, with lxml (as the library, not just the parser) - which, unlike BS, uses xpath - the search expression would have used proper casing, as in (for example): `doc.xpath('//Inflection[@Form="best.f.sing."]/text()')`.